# Scope of a return value of a function

Tags: c++, scope

```
class obj {
};

obj func() {
    return obj();
}

int main() {
   obj& o = func(); // possible?
}
```

What is the scope the return value of a function that returns objects by value?
in other word, inside the scope that this function is called, is it possible to take the reference of the returned by value object?

Comment: const obj& o = func(); // possible

Comment: So taking the reference is valid. Is the const revelant?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How come a non-const reference cannot bind to a temporary object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object)

Comment: [*GotW #88: A Candidate For the “Most Important `const`”*](https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can bind a reference to the return value of a function. This extends the lifetime of the returned object to that of the reference (if it's global or function-local), or to the end of the current function (if the reference is a data member).

However, you cannot bind a temporary (prvalue) to a non-`const` lvalue reference. So it's like this:

```
obj& o = func(); // illegal, because non-const lvalue ref
const obj& o = func(); // fine, lifetime extended
obj&& o = func(); // fine, lifetime extended
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot take non-const reference of temporary.

You may do

- `obj o = func();        // new obj created but copy constructor may be ellided`
- `const obj& o = func(); // lifetime extended`
- `obj&& o = func();      // lifetime extended`

Comment: could you maybe explain why "non-const" is invalid?

Comment: @mkmostafa: That is well-covered on thousands of existing questions, not to mention your C++ textbook.

Answer (score 1):

It's not allowed by the language to take a non-const reference of temporary, you can however:

```
const obj& o = func();
// or
obj&& o = func();
// or simply
obj o = func();
```